# Наложить текст на картинку БЕЗ растягивания картинки на 100% экрана

Tags: html, css

Нужно наложить текст на картинку, и первая же ссылка в гугле дает это:

```css
  .container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Image Text</h2>
  <p>How to place text over an image:</p>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/22/5a/43225aba74ba46ba733f83ec5084e73d.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
    <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

И оно успешно кладёт текст поверх картинки! Но есть фатальный недостаток -

```
<img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
```

У изображения всегда ширина - 100% от родительского объекта. Это не всегда удобно. Как сделать так, чтобы  оно работало с изначальным размером изображения, не растягивая его?

Comment: Вам не подходит изменять размер у `.container`?

Comment: делай изображение фоновым и с помощью background-size можно управлять размером картинки

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Не лучший вариант - картинки будут спаунится автоматически, лентой, и каждая картинка может быть в ширину и 1024 px и 200 px и какой угодно, как загрузит юзер. Вручную задавать размер контейнера - значит узнавать какой размер у каждой картинки, кодом, и присваивать его же контейнеру. Думаете, хороший способ?

Comment: @Grundy это явное задание размера, а хотелось бы чтобы он просто был своего размера. Ну и если делать картинку бэкграундом, сразу возникают всякие вопросы типа спауна чего то ниже, выше и вокруг него, это всю структуру переверстывать. Нет способа проще? Код выше полностью меня устраивает, кроме растягивание изображения. Если бы сделать `width:auto` или вовсе её не указывать, но сохранить возможность спаунить надписи поверх картинки - было бы замечательно.

Comment: можно просто не делать `width:100%` у картинки, а контейнеру установить `display:inline-block` в этом случае картинка его растянет по своей ширине

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.image {
  display: block;
}

.image .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/4sJkn2n.png">
    <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
    <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/arThuso.png">
    <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
    <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </div>
</div>
```